# Language specific characters in URL

Tags: url, character-encoding

Colleagues from work have created API endpoint which uses language specific characters in url. This api url looks like

```
http://somedomain.com/someapi/somemethod/zażółć/gęślą/jaźń
```

Is this OK or is it a bad approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, that's not a valid URL but web browsers and other clients finesse it. The script that characters are from is not an issue but structural characters like "/?#" could be. You'll have to consider what to do when they show up in data that you are "pasting" into your URLs.

An HTTP URL is:

- an ASCII-encoded scheme (in this case the protocol "http")
- a punycode-encoded, ASCII-encoded domain
- a %-encoded, ASCII-encoded, server-defined sequence of octets for the path, optional query, and optional hash.

See [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

The assumption that everyone makes—quite reasonably because it is the predominant practice—is that the path, query, and hash are text. There is no text but encoded text. So, some character encoding is involved. Where %-encoding is needed outside of structural characters, browsers are going to assume UTF-8. If you don't want browsers to do the %-encoding, use valid URLs by doing it yourself with the character encoding that you are using.

As the world is standardizing on UTF-8 (where applicable), the HTML DOM has also with the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function. Clients using JavaScript in a web browser are likely to use this function, either directly or through some library.

UTF-8 encoded, %-encoded (and, then on the wire, ASCII-encoded) version of your URL that my browser created:

> http://somedomain.com/someapi/somemethod/za%C5%BC%C3%B3%C5%82%C4%87/g%C4%99%C5%9Bl%C4%85/ja%C5%BA%C5%84

(You can see this yourself using your browser's dev tools [F12 key, network tab] or a packet sniffer [e.g., Wireshark or Fiddler]. What you gave as a URL is never seen on the wire.)

Your server application probably understands that just fine. In any case, it is your server's rules that the client complies with. If your API uses UTF-8 encoded, %-encoded URLs then just document that. (But phrase it in a way that doesn't confuse people who do that already without knowing.)